# XCode error: "GDB:Program received signal: "SIGABRT"."

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, xcode3.2

I am writing a simple application using cocos2d 0.99.5, the iPhone SDK is 4.2. I have run my application on device, but when I press the button to switch CCScenes, sometimes the app suddenly has no response and XCode received the error:"GDB:Program received signal:"SIGABRT". "

This issue happens by accident. You have to press the transition button many times to reproduce this bug.

I have learned that SIGABRT is raised by the abort() function. abort() is called by the standard assert() macro when an assertion fails. But there is no assert function in my program.

Could anyone tell me how does this problem happen, and how to solve this problem?  I don't know what to do next now.

Comment: Look at your debugger console and see what error message was raised.

Comment: 2010-12-23 02:51:21.485 RotateClock[4087:307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CCTransitionFade orientationChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2380c0'

Comment: -(void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
 // ...
 [[CCDirector sharedDirector].runningScene orientationChanged:notification];
}

Comment: I am guessing that you are using Cocos2D and from the header files it looks like runningScene is of type CCScene which is of type [CCNode](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/source/browse/trunk/cocos2d/CCNode.h?r=1481) which does not look to have -(void)orientationChanged: defined. I may be wrong since I never used Cocos2d before but verify.

Comment: Yes Joe, you are right. I think I have found the answer. When I do the scene transition, the current scene becomes CCTransitionFade scene, and at this moment when the program received device orientation change message, it would call the orientationChanged:notification function, but there is no such function in CCTransitionFade class. I have defined this function in CCTransitionFade and now it works fine. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved. See the comments above.

Comment: Not only that, but I think it'd be a good idea to include the relevant comment content in this answer for clarity

Answer (score 0):

If you get SIGABRT when app starts check your XIBS

Open each XIB

Check the Files Owner in each in the Identity Inspector

Make sure the class mentioned is the correct one and class exists (I had renamed some files and it failed)

Start with

```
MainWindow.xib
RootViewController.xib
```

Check Class names in Identity Inspector is ok.

Place breakpoints in 
AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//if it enters this method then MainWindow.xib ok
```

STEP 2 - in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions place another breakpoint on

```
   self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

In the RootViewController.m (or whatever sub class of VC self.viewController in AppDelegate is) place a break point in

```
viewDidLoad
```

If it crashes here check RootViewController.xib (or what ever class the first VC is)
and check Class is correct for Files Owner

iterate down through all View controllers 
look for initWithNibName to find what XIBs are called.
In each check the Class name in the XIb is set correctly.